# Distinguishing Even and Odd Numbers with Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a problem that I'm having a tough time figuring out, figured I would see if someone could point me in the right direction.

I am writing a recursive method(s) that takes an `int` for it's parameter, then displays all squared values of the odd numbers (top down) then all squared values of the even numbers (again top down)

E.g 6 would output

> 25, 9, 1, 36, 16, 4

My approach would be to have 3 methods. One `int recursiveOdd(int num)` that would calculate and output to console the squared values of odd. One `int recursiveEven(int num)` that would calculate and output to console the squared values of even. And one method `void passToRecursive(int num)` that simply takes the number and calls the other two methods.

My question is how do I approach the first method, finding the highest odd number then finding the highest even number without using a loop.

Obviously, the max number is going to be whatever `int` was passed from `main`. 
I simply can't think of how I would find the highest odd w/o a loop.

Comment: What is recursive about this task?

Comment: @V.K., the fact that it must be completed using a recursive function...

Answer (score 3):

If the given number is `N`, then the highest even number is found by taking half, truncating, and multiplying by 2:

```
(N / 2) * 2
```

The highest odd number is a little trickier: subtract 1, find the highest even number for *that*, and then add 1:

```
((N-1) / 2) * 2 + 1
```

That gives you your two numbers (truncate / floor as needed).  Now, for the recursion: you need your base case (finishing condition) and your recursion case.

Base case: `if N <= 0`, return without printing anything.
Recursion: `print N*N;` recur with the value (N-2).

By the way, note that the recursive routine is *identical* for the odd and even cases: you need only one recursive routine. Call it twice from the **passTo** routine, once each with the odd and even numbers you found at the start.

Finally, please consider changing the name **passToRecursive**.  It's a little misleading, since it is not, itself, a recursive routine; it's merely a handler. Someone calling it doesn't care that it has recursive subroutines. Instead, give it a name descriptive of what it does.

Comment: That's what I had in mind for the recursion. Was simply getting the number to pass I was struggling with. You're idea is perfect!  Also, I don't see how the name is misleading? It does exactly what it says it's going to do. I have no problem changing it, just didn't personally find it misleading myself. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can I ask why you're using two slashes for division? That makes the rest of the line a comment.

Comment: @CareyGregory: He seems to be using it for truncated/integer division *a la* Python.

Comment: Then -1 given that the question is tagged C++ and the code provided  is not C++ (it won't even compile). Fix your syntax to be C++ rather than Python and I'll undo my downvote.

Comment: Was confused by that as well. Glad someone else said something

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for poiner in the right direction, try transforming this into C++

```
function oddSquare(int value) {
  if (value mod 2 == 0) value --;
  if (value > 0) {  /* Stop when we get too small */
    print value * value;
    oddSquare(--value); /* Decrement to next lower value and recurse
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't use loops, which an if is.

Comment: @JeffreyDilley: A [conditional statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)) (a.k.a if statement) is not a [loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Loops).

Comment: @John: You probably intended to use `while` instead of `if`, no? BTW, aside from the fact that an if-statement is not a loop, this post is neither an algorithmically-correct answer or one using the right language. It will likely attract hungry downvoters.

Answer (score 2):

We beginners should help each other.:)

I can suggest a solution that is based on using a static variable inside the recursive function.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

void OddEvenSquares( unsigned int n )
{
    static unsigned long long int even;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        if ( n % 2 )
        {
            std::cout << static_cast<unsigned long long int>( n ) * n << ' ';
            OddEvenSquares( n - 1 );
        }
        else
        {
            even += 2;
            OddEvenSquares( n - 1 );
            std::cout << even * even << ' ';
            even -= 2;
        }
    }        
}

int main()
{
    const unsigned int N = 10;

    for ( unsigned int i = 1; i <= N; i++ )
    {
        OddEvenSquares( i );
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        
}
```

Its output is

```
1 
1 4 
9 1 4 
9 1 16 4 
25 9 1 16 4 
25 9 1 36 16 4 
49 25 9 1 36 16 4 
49 25 9 1 64 36 16 4 
81 49 25 9 1 64 36 16 4 
81 49 25 9 1 100 64 36 16 4
```

Or the function can have a second parameter with a default argument.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream & OddEvenSquares( unsigned int n, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    static unsigned long long int even;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {        
        if ( n % 2 )
        {
            std::cout << static_cast<unsigned long long int>( n ) * n << ' ';
            OddEvenSquares( n - 1, os );
        }
        else
        {
            even += 2;
            OddEvenSquares( n - 1, os );
            os << even * even << ' ';
            even -= 2;
        }
    }

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    const unsigned int N = 10;

    for ( unsigned int i = 1; i <= N; i++ )
    {
        OddEvenSquares( i ) << std::endl;
    }        
}
```

The program output will be the same as shown above.

As for your approach when there are two separate recursive functions for odd and even numbers then function `passToRecursive` can look the following way

```
void passToRecursive( int num )
{
    if ( num > 0 )
    { 
        int odd, even;

        if ( num % 2 )
        {
            odd = num;
            even = odd - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            even = num;
            odd = even - 1;
        }

        recursiveOdd( odd );
        recursiveEven( even );
    }
}
```

You may change the inner if-else statement to the conditional operator. For example

```
void passToRecursive( int num )
{
    if ( num > 0 )
    { 
        int odd, even;

        num % 2 ? ( odd  = num, even = odd  - 1 ) 
                : ( even = num, odd  = even - 1 );

        recursiveOdd( odd );
        recursiveEven( even );
    }
}
```

In fact you even do not need to define two recursive functions because their bodies can be the same.

So function `passToRecursive` can look like

```
void passToRecursive( int num )
{
    if ( num > 0 )
    { 
        int odd, even;

        num % 2 ? ( odd  = num, even = odd  - 1 ) 
                : ( even = num, odd  = even - 1 );

        recursiveSquares( odd );
        recursiveSquares( even );
    }
}
```

Pay attention to this statement

```
std::cout << static_cast<unsigned long long int>( n ) * n << ' ';
```

The product of two integers can be greater than the maximum value that can be stored in type `int` or `unsigned int`. So you need to use some larger integer type as for example `long long int` or `unsigned long long int` for the product.

As usually my answer is the best.:)